# Occasion and Opportunity

Tags: meaning, word-choice, vocabulary

```
At the same time, large companies may take ___ of smaller suppliers by delaying payment.
The offer continues, so why not take ___ ?
The attacker was ideally placed to take ___ of this.
```

Please, I want to choose one of the following to complete each sentence.

a) occasion
b) opportunity
c) possibility
d) advantage

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it appears to be about completing an assignment without seeking to understand the basis for the answer.

Comment: As bib says, make a good-faith attempt to solve the problem yourself first, show us what you've got, ask about any issues with your existing approach. That's not something we ask of you, that's something we ask of all homework questions (and in fact of all questions, period). You know, the whole learning-to-fish-vs-getting-a-fish thing. Also, why is this tagged "will-be-going"? (@_@)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All three blanks will have same answer: *advantage*.

Comment: thank you, in fact this questions i bring it from a lot of exams, because i have exam soon, so i wanna make sure about my answers.

Comment: @framawi : I have edited my previous answer.Please have a look "bother and intrude". Best of luck for exams..